# Mongoose - How to populate a sub document on condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm new to Mongoose I don't know how to populate on condition.
So this is my model :

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
    products: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product' }],
    remarks: {type: String, lowercase: true}
});
mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);


const ProductSchema = new Schema({
   reference: {type: String}
   status: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'ProductStatus'}
});
mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);

const ProductStatus = new Schema({
    name: {type: String}
});

const CountrySchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String}
});
mongoose.model("Country", CountrySchema);
```

I have a **getOrderById** methods

```
export const getOrderById = async (req, res) => {
let id = req.params.id;
try {
    await orderModel
        .findById(id)
        .populate({
            path: 'products',
            populate: {
              path: 'country',
              model: 'Country'
            }
         })
         .populate({
            path: 'products',
            populate: {
              path: 'status',
              model: 'ProductStatus'
            }
         })
        .exec(function (err, orders) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.status(200).json(orders);
        });
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
}
}
```

And now I would like to show in the order lists all products that have the status Received in France.

Comment: Can you show the Country model, because it is reference and not shown in you code?

Comment: the country model is similar like the ProductStatus model

Comment: I just updated it  @AhmedAgiza  thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I guess you also missed reference to the country in the product schema, so assuming these are your corrected schemas:

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
    products: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    }],
    remarks: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true
    }
});
const Order = mongoose.model("Order", OrderSchema);


const ProductSchema = new Schema({
    reference: {
        type: String
    },
    country: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Country'
    },
    status: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ProductStatus'
    }
});
const Product = mongoose.model("Product", ProductSchema);

const ProductStatusSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});
const ProductStatus = mongoose.model("ProductStatus", ProductStatusSchema);

const CountrySchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    }
});
const Country = mongoose.model("Country", CountrySchema);
```

As far as I understand you want to only show the products, whose country's name is 'France' and ProductStatus' name is 'Received', these kind of operations are done through [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Your query may look like this assuming you want to do it one query:

```
const getOrderById = async (req, res) => {
        let id = req.params.id.toString();
        const ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId
        try {
            const aggregationStages = [{
                $match: {
                    _id: ObjectId(id) //It is important to cast to ObjectId in aggregations
                }
            }, {
                $lookup: {
                    from: 'products',
                    let: {
                        productIds: '$products'
                    },
                    pipeline: [{
                        $match: {
                            $expr: {
                                $in: ['$_id', '$$productIds']
                            }
                        }
                    }, {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: 'countries',
                            localField: 'country',
                            foreignField: '_id',
                            as: 'country'
                        }
                    }, {
                        $lookup: {
                            from: 'productstatuses',
                            localField: 'status',
                            foreignField: '_id',
                            as: 'status'
                        }
                    }, {
                        $match: {
                            'country.name': 'France',
                            'status.name': 'Received'
                        }
                    }],
                    as: 'products'
                }
            }];
            await orderModel.aggregate(aggregationStages)
                .exec(function (err, orders) { // The return is an array btw.
                    if (err) {
                        res.send(err);
                    }
                    res.status(200).json(orders);
                });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

If you feel the aggregation is complicated you may resort to breaking it to smaller simpler queries. Feel free to ask if you need more explanation/modification.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ahmed Agiza you help me a lot its work very well. Now i'm gonna go read  the MongoDb docs and after i can ask you some question. THANKS A LOT

Comment: @Ahmed above query is in mongodb format. I need a solution in mongoose format. Check this https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html but not working.

Comment: @Sameer I am not sure I get you, but this example is executed through Mongoose not direct MongoDB driver, aggregations are available normally in Mongoose. Populate works for simpler operations, not this type.

Comment: @AhmedAgiza got it